# How from imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo can I retrieve the content of the picked photo in a NSData object?

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

How from `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` can i retrieve the content of the photo the user select in a NSData object ?

Comment: What data do you want? The PNG representation of the UIImage? The JPG representation of the UIImage? The raw data of the associated asset?

Comment: And update your question with your relevant code showing what you have done and what you need help with.

Comment: @mady, i want to put in nsdata the content of the picture a user select, what wrong with this question ?

Answer (score 0):

The image data is sitting at the URL provided as the value for the `imageURL` key (in Objective-C, `UIImagePickerControllerImageURL`). Load it with `dataWithContentsOfURL:`.